# delete character at back

Tags: javascript, jquery

12:00:00:12

How to remove 6 character from the back? the output would be 12:00, I can't use substring to get the from the front to get the 6 char, because it can be 9:00 so it's just 4 char instead of 5.

Comment: Are you sure you will always remove 6 or 5 chars?

Comment: @CapitanFindus so what is the best solution? detect the `:`?

Comment: You could check if the length is 5 or 6, than `substring`. But ONLY if value is 5 or 6 chars length. Or you could get index of second `:` then substring

Comment: Your string can be `12:00:00:8`?

Comment: @JenniferAniston Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better if you use **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** function, and take the first and second items in splited array.

```js
var my_string ="12:00:00:12";
var array_splited = my_string.split(':');

console.log( array_splited[0] + ':' + array_splited[1] ); //12:00
```

If you want it in single line, e.g :

```
my_string.split(':')[0] + ':' + my_string.split(':')[1];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can it be in one line? I'm doing formatting within a loop.

Comment: ah really work using split(), thanks so much Zakaria!

Answer (score 3):

I think @ZakariaAcharki is a better solution but if you want make it by substring try this:

```
str = '12:00:00:12';
str.substring(0,str.length-6);
```

Comment: This is the way you would do it, messing about with arrays or a regex is a bit crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the length and than go back 6 chars e.g.

```
str = '12:00:00:12'
str = str.substring(0,str.length - 6);
```

But you may better match with

```
str = '12:00:00:12'.match(/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+/)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression with `.match()` method will do:

```js
var str1 = '12:00:00:12';
var str2 = '9:40:00:12';

var regex = /(\d+)+:+(\d\d)/g;

var newStr1 = str1.match(regex)[0];
var newStr2 = str2.match(regex)[0];

document.querySelector('#one').textContent = JSON.stringify(newStr1);
document.querySelector('#two').textContent = JSON.stringify(newStr2);
```

```html
'12:00:00:12' <pre id='one'></pre>
<hr>
'9:40:00:12' <pre id='two'></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "12:00:00:12";
var newStrArr = str.split(":");
newStrArr.pop();
newStrArr.pop();
newStrArr.join(":");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and best solution:

Use **[slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)** function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
    var str = '12:00:00:12';
    alert(str.slice(0,-6));
});
```

> Output: 12:00

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaz4584/759n74he/)**

Answer (score 0):

If the time will always be in the form (0-12):(00-59);(00-59) then you could use regex and the function .match() to get the time in the format you would like:

```
current_time = '12:00:00'

time_formatted = current_time.match(/\d+:\d+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `split` and `join`.

**EG 1:**

```js
var num = "12:00:00:12";
console.log(num.split(':', 2).join(':'));
```

**EG 2:**

```js
var num = "9:00:00:12";
console.log(num.split(':', 2).join(':'));
```